# Show/hide text areas in mvc view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have three text areas that I want to show/hide when I click on each link. I can get it to show when I click on the link but can't get it to hide when I click on the link.

jquery:

```
      <script>
        $('#responsibilityLink').click(function () {
        $('#div1').show();
       });

    $('#descriptionLink').click(function () {
        $('#div2').show();
    });

    $('#responseLink').click(function () {
        $('#div3').show();
    });

   </script>
```

html:

```
       <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a id="responsibilityLink" 
              href="#">Responsibility</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div1" style="display:none" class="col-md-12">
                        <div>
                            <div id="editor"></div>
                            <textarea name="Responsibility"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a id="descriptionLink" href="#">Description</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div2" style="display:none" class="col-md-12">
                        <div>
                            <textarea name="Description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a id="responseLink" href="#">Add Response</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div3" style="display:none" class="col-md- 
                  12">
                        <div>
                            <textarea name="Response"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

the show works but how do I hide the text area when I click on each link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using toggle instead, it will switch back and forth between showing/hiding the element:

```js
        $('#responsibilityLink').click(function () {
        $('#div1').toggle();
       });

    $('#descriptionLink').click(function () {
        $('#div2').toggle();
    });

    $('#responseLink').click(function () {
        $('#div3').toggle();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a id="responsibilityLink" 
              href="#">Responsibility</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div1" style="display:none" class="col-md-12">
                        <div>
                            <div id="editor"></div>
                            <textarea name="Responsibility"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a id="descriptionLink" href="#">Description</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div2" style="display:none" class="col-md-12">
                        <div>
                            <textarea name="Description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <a id="responseLink" href="#">Add Response</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="div3" style="display:none" class="col-md- 
                  12">
                        <div>
                            <textarea name="Response"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```